# issues with class friendship and inheritance

Tags: c++

I feel like I'm missing something obvious here, but I have a class that declares another class as a friend yet does not seem to have access to its private members.

I have minimized the issue as follows:

**Widget.hpp**:

```
template<typename T> class Foo;

template<typename T, typename U>
class WidgetBase
{
protected:
    T* ptr;
public:
    WidgetBase(T* ptr) : ptr{ptr} {}
    virtual void f() = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class WidgetDerived : public WidgetBase<typename Foo<T>::Bar, T>
{
public:
    using WidgetBase<typename Foo<T>::Bar, T>::WidgetBase;
    using WidgetBase<typename Foo<T>::Bar, T>::ptr;
    virtual void f() { ptr->x = 9; }
};
```

**Foo.hpp**:

```
#include "Widget.hpp"

template<typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    struct Bar
    {
        T x;
        explicit Bar(T x) : x{x} {}
    };
public:
    Bar* bar;
    explicit Foo(T x) : bar{new Bar{x}} {}
    ~Foo() { delete bar; }
    WidgetDerived<T> foo_widget() { WidgetDerived<T> widget{bar}; return widget; }
    friend class WidgetBase<Bar, T>;
    friend class WidgetDerived<T>;
};
```

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "Foo.hpp"

int main()
{
    Foo<int> foo(7);
    auto widget = foo.foo_widget();
}
```

Using GCC 7.3.0, I attempt to compile with: `g++ -o main main.cpp -pedantic -Wall -Werror -Wconversion -std=c++1z` and receive the following error message:

```
In file included from Foo.hpp:1:0,
                 from main.cpp:1:
Widget.hpp: In instantiation of 'class WidgetDerived<int>':
main.cpp:6:34:   required from here
Widget.hpp:14:7: error: 'struct Foo<int>::Bar' is private within this context
 class WidgetDerived : public WidgetBase<typename Foo<T>::Bar, T>
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from main.cpp:1:0:
Foo.hpp:7:12: note: declared private here
     struct Bar
            ^~~
```

Note that I declare both `WidgetBase` and `WidgetDerived` as friends of `Foo`. What am I missing here?

Comment: It seems legit and compiles with clang, so seems like gcc big to me. But I’m no language lawyer.

Comment: @Jonas Yeah, I just installed Clang and tried it. It does indeed compile with Clang.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a GCC (G++) bug, see [bug report](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82478). The code compiles just fine with clang  6.0.0. However, clang 5.0.0 also reject the code.

Unfortunately I can only suggest these two possible solutions. 1) make the struct public, or 2) compile with a recent version of clang.